# My Conditional Tags not Working

Tags: conditional-tags

I'm just a starter in WordPress. I [found](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_PAGE_Page) the one I'm looking for but I can't make it work.

I want to add a script when the travel page is shown and it's hidden when the user navigates to the rest of the page.

This is the code snippet under **Footer.php**:

```
<?php 
  wp_footer(); 
  is_page( 'need-travel-insurance' ) {
    echo "For travel.";
  }
?>
```

If I start to echo something, the whole footer including widgets does not completely show. What could I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`if` condition check is missing in your code. Try this:

```
<?php 
  wp_footer(); 
  if(is_page( 'need-travel-insurance' )){
    echo "For travel.";
  }
 ?>
```